# Exporting a database to .bacpac while excluding certain tables using SqlPackage

Tags: sql-server, sqlpackage

We regularly use SqlPackage.exe to export a SQL Server (usually from Azure SQL) database for use in other contexts - local development, issue investigation, etc.

This works great, but we have a few situations where the size of the exported database .bacpac file is a problem - team members with poor internet connections, etc.

A large portion of the size of our database comes from one particular table that's not often needed in these non-production scenarios.

Is there any way to tell the `SqlPackage /a:Export` command to skip exporting data from that particular table?

I know there's a way to specify specific tables that you DO want included using `/p:TableData=<table name>`, but we have hundreds of tables and add more often, so that would be a maintenance nightmare.